# Do while Loop - I only want to exit this loop when user has entered 1 or 2 into the prompt or selects the cancel in prompt

Tags: javascript, html, loops

i have created a do while loop in which I add a prompt user. If a user enter 1 then it should show account Balance variable and if a user enter 2 then it should ask another prompt in which it asks user to add money to account Balance variable. The problem is I only want to exit the loop if the user has entered  1 or 2 in the prompt or if the user selected the cancel button in prompt. However, I am facing this issue where whatever I enter into the prompt the loop exit itself. I didn't understand this problem. Can someone please help me regarding this. Thank You.

**Javascript code**

```
let h2 = document.getElementById("gurkiran");
do {
    let accountBalance = 4300;
    let userEntry = prompt("Enter a number -  1 or 2");
    if(userEntry === "1"){
        h2.textContent = `Your account balance is: $${accountBalance}`;
    }else if (userEntry === "2"){
        let userDeposit = prompt("How much money you want to deposit ?");
        accountBalance+= parseInt(userDeposit);
        h2.textContent = `$${userDeposit} has been deposited to your account. Your new balance is: $${accountBalance}`;
    }
} while (userEntry == "1" || userEntry == "2");
```

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hello </title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2 id="gurkiran"></h2>
    <p>Thank you for banking with us.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the variable outside of the loop otherwise it's out of scope when you check it in the while condition. Also, you should have some way of escaping the loop when you press cancel, I've added a break for that case.

Please see the below code snippet.

```js
let h2 = document.getElementById("gurkiran");
let userEntry
do {
  userEntry = prompt("Enter a number -  1 or 2");
  if (!userEntry) break;
  let accountBalance = 4300;

  if (userEntry === "1") {
    h2.textContent = `Your account balance is: $${accountBalance}`;
  } else if (userEntry === "2") {
    let userDeposit = prompt("How much money you want to deposit ?");
    accountBalance += parseInt(userDeposit);
    h2.textContent = `$${userDeposit} has been deposited to your account. Your new balance is: $${accountBalance}`;
  }
} while (userEntry !== "1" && userEntry !== "2");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>hello </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="gurkiran"></h2>
  <p>Thank you for banking with us.</p>

</body>

</html>
```